# Losing global variables when require is used

Tags: node.js, scope, express

I am trying to globally define some things (underscore library, mongoose, db connection, eventually a permissions object)

app.js

```
/* module dependencies */
const express = require('express');
const auth = require('http-auth');
const underscore = require('underscore');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const db = require('./library/db');
/*end module dependencies */


/*routes files*/
const post = require('./routes/post');
/* end route files */


/* start the app instance */
var app = express();


/* authentication */
var basic = auth({
  authRealm : "Private area.",
  authList : ['Shi:many222', 'Lota:123456']
});
/* end authentication*/


/* pass app as an argument to the use method */
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(expressValidator);
  app.use(db);
  //app.use(underscore);
  /* config debugging */
  app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
  });
  /* production instance */
  app.configure('production', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
  });
  /* end config debugging */
});


/* start route management */
app.get('/post', function(req, res) {
  basic.apply(req, res, function(username) {
    post.use(app);
    post.findAll(req, res);
  });
});
app.get('/post/:id', function(req, res) {
  post.findById(req, res);
});


/* port management */
var port = 8000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening: port: '+port);
```

post.js

```
    // Module dependencies
const underscore = require("underscore");


// placeholder for app instance
var app;


// add a use function to exports that we can access from our app
exports.use = function (appInstance) {
  // make app instance available in post.js
  app = appInstance;
};


/* find all rows */
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
  console.log('Post:findAll');
  app.db.collection('Post', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({},{limit: 100}).toArray(function(err, items) {
      res.send(exports.parseModels(items));
    });
  });
};


/* parse a single or all items passed to it for formatting */
exports.parseModels = function (items) {
  underscore.each(items, function(key, val) {
    console.log('underscore parsed an object');
  });
  return items;
};
```

db.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server,
  Db = mongo.Db,
  BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
var db = new Db('website', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    //do an error here
  }
});

exports.db = db;
```

I am having problem getting the DB in the correct scope, currently when a query is called inside post.js, I get this error:

```
    ost:findAll
TypeError: Cannot call method 'collection' of undefined
    at Object.exports.findAll (/Github/-api-v3/routes/post.js:19:10)
    at /Github/-api-v3/app.js:53:10
    at Basic.apply (/Github/-api-v3/node_modules/http-auth/lib/auth/basic.js:48:4)
    at /Github/-api-v3/app.js:51:9
    at callbacks (/Github/-api-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/Github/-api-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/Github/-api-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Github/-api-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/Github/-api-v3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/Github/-api-v3/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but `app` is not some sort of reference to the global variable space; you've declared it as a variable that's local to `app.js`.  You can make it global by initializing it as `global.app = ...` and then you can reference `app` in your other modules like `post.js` to get a things like `app.db`.  Also, what are you doing with the `basic.apply(...` call?

Comment: If you need underscore in post.js, why don't you just 'require('underscore')'? Each module is self contained, variables, unless exported, are not accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Every module is run in a closure with its own scope. That means that any variables you define will only be accessible within that module. Any methods or variables that you want to make visible to the outside should be added to the `module.exports` object.

If you really have to define a global variable you need to add that as properties to the `global` object, but this is something that should be kept to an absolute minimum.

The proper way to do it is to require any depending modules within each and every module that you use. So you should do `var _ = require("underscore");` in `post.js` if you want `_` to reference to underscore.

If you need `post.js` to be aware of your `app` instance, you should pass it as an argument to a function that is available in the `module.exports` object for `post.js`.

**post.js**

```
// Module dependencies
const _ = require("underscore");

// placeholder for app instance
var app;

// add a use function to exports that 
// we can access from our app
exports.use = function (appInstance) {
    // make app instance available in post.js
    app = appInstance;
    // app.db is also accessible
}

// add the rest of the methods here
```

**app.js**

```
// Module dependencies
const express = require('express');
const auth = require('http-auth');
const _ = require('underscore');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const post = require('./routes/post');

// create app instance
var app = express();

// require db into app.db
app.db = require("./db");

// pass app as an argument to the use method
post.use(app);
```

*Note: I prefer to use const for dependencies to make it easier to distinct from ordinary variables/instances. Also note that `exports` is a shorthand for `module.exports`.*

Comment: Hello this is a fantastic piece of code and Ive learnt alot from it. Thanks! However I am still having problem with my DB connection being in scope. I have updated my original post with the updated code. Thanks again.

Comment: @azz0r I can't see how/where you are attaching `db` to `app.db`. You are treating `db` as a middleware. Try with `app.db = db` instead of `app.use(db)`.

Comment: I updated app.js to be: var app = express(); app.db = db; and now I get: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'collection'
    at Object.exports.findAll (/Github/-api-v3/routes/post.js:19:10)

Comment: And you are sure you are doing the `post.use(app);` at the bottom of `app.js`?

Comment: app.get('/post', function(req, res) {
  basic.apply(req, res, function(username) {
    post.use(app);
    post.findAll(req, res);
  });
});

Comment: @azz0r `post.use(app);` should be called outside of the route, as in my example.

Comment: okay, same error.

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'collection'
    at Object.exports.findAll (/Github/-api-v3/routes/post.js:19:10)